# SpelEvaluationException: EL1010E: Property or field 'messageContext' cannot be set on object of type 'RequestControlContextImpl'

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-webflow

I'm using Spring Web Flow to make flow for making an order. User must authorize 
 and enter his username at the flow, if user enter username of another person my flow will reject his order and put "Login as this user" in message context. But, unfortunately my flow crashes with this exception:

```
 org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1010E: Property or field 'messageContext' cannot be set on object of type 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl' - maybe not public or not writable?
```

My flow code

```
<view-state id="login" >
    <transition on="loginEntered" to="lookupUser" validate="true"/>
</view-state>

<action-state id="msgcnt" >
    <evaluate expression="orderFlowService.msgCnt(messageContext)"  result="messageContext" />
    <transition on="yes" to="login" />
</action-state>

// other flows omitted
```

my msgCnt method:

```
public boolean msgCnt(MessageContext context){
  context.addMessage(new MessageBuilder().info().source("check").defaultText("Увійдіть як цей користувач !").build());
  return true;
}
```

and jsp-view:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
 <head><title>Увійдіть!</title></head>
 <body>
  <h2>Нове замовлення!</h2>
  <p/>
  <h3>Введіть ваш логін. Якщо у вас його немає,введіть як бажаєте себе 
 назвати!</h3>
  <c:forEach items="${messageContext.getMessagesBySource(check)}" 
var="message">
    <h3>${message}</h3>
  </c:forEach>
  <form:form>
    <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
    <input type="text" name="login" /><br/>

    <input type="submit" name="_eventId_loginEntered" value="Продовжити"/>
  </form:form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* what's happening is that this line:

```
<evaluate expression="orderFlowService.msgCnt(messageContext)"  result="messageContext" />
```

Is trying to put the result of of `orderFlowService.msgCnt()` (which is a boolean "true") directly into a place that it isn't expected, with the name "messageContext", which could possibly even be an existing object. I'm guessing at some internals here, but thinking maybe this isn't what you meant/needed to do?

Because you pass `messageContext` in to the method and add messages inside there, I think you don't want to specify a `result` at all.

Comment: Yep, you are right! I replaced return value by void and removed 'result' field in flow, but now i'm just getting redirected to my page, without error text.

Comment: `messageContext` is a reserved el variable. see https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/el.html#el-variable-messageContext